# capturing image using c#, HTML (Not HTML 5) and javascript in my website

Tags: c#, javascript, html, asp.net, webcam

I have a requirement to capture an image from a webcam and I came up with a few solutions myself too. but there are a few conditions in the way I achieve this result. They are:

- I cannot use HTML5 (compatibility issues with most browsers).
- I tried using an external swf file. It works but I cant use it to integrate with the current project because I will have to decompile and compile the swf every time I want to make a modification (Not something I prefer). So i cant use swf.
- Cant use silverlight.
- Basically I would like this to be possible using HTML,javascript and c#.

I tried a few solutions from codeproject and other websites, none I came across satisfies my conditions.Does anyone have any idea what to do ??

Comment: i don't think it's possible using just html 4 and javascript. You say that C# is allowed... but is it running on the client? I assume it is only on the server. So on the client you only allow html4 and javascript. This is too limiting.

Comment: Exactly its very limiting and I was wondering if there is any workaround.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not possible to do using a browser with HTML 4 and/or javascript. All browsers run in a restricted space known as the [sandbox](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sandbox_%28computer_security%29).

> > In computer security, a sandbox is a security mechanism for separating running programs. It is often used to execute untested code, or untrusted programs from unverified third-parties, suppliers, untrusted users and untrusted websites.

The only way you could capture something from a web cam would be to have client software running that connects to the camera, grabs a still, and then uploads the image to a web site, web service, or web api.

Comment: interesting. let me do a little bit of research on this and if what u say is applicable i will accept your answer.